# Eigen 3 SpaseMatrix<bool> - SparseMatrix<bool> multiplication warning on GCC 8.2

Tags: c++, c++14, sparse-matrix, eigen3

I want to multiply Boolean sparse matrices using Eigen 3.3.

The following code compiles on GCC 8.2 and Clang 6:

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<bool> A { 3, 3 };
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<bool> B { 3, 1 };

    A(0, 1) = true;
    A(1, 0) = true;
    A(2, 2) = true;
    B(0, 0) = true;
    B(0, 2) = true;

    std::cout << A * B << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints the result I was expecting, `[1 0 1]`, and it compiles without any warnings on Clang 6. However, on GCC 8.2, I got the following annoying warning:

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/ConservativeSparseSparseProduct.h:65:25: warning: ‘*’ in boolean context, suggest ‘&&’ instead [-Wint-in-bool-context]
       values[i] = x * y;
```

Is there a way of override the Boolean multiply to logical or, `&&`, only when multiplying sparse matrices? Or is there any other workaround? I cannot switch to dense matrices/arrays, since I'm working with really large matrices in the real code. Even with this warning, the performance of this operation is really good.

I've already tried:

- Using the development version of Eigen from its mercurial repo: It raises the same warning;
- `(A * B).template cast<bool>` as described in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537884/eigen-3-3-sparsematrixbool-operations) : It raises the same warning;
- `A && B`: It raises an runtime error (it seems that it tries to execute a scalar/coefficient wise product): `Assertion aLhs.rows() == aRhs.rows() && aLhs.cols() == aRhs.cols()' failed.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use `-Wall` as a GCC compiler flag.

You can turn off that specific warning by `-Wall -Wno-int-in-bool-context`

Comment: Hi @Ripi2, thanks for the answer and it will be a nice workaround by now. Since Eigen 3 is an expressions template library, I think it's likely to have a way of overriding the SparseMatrix<bool> product implementation out of the box, but I couldn't find it (maybe I just need to improve my duckduckgo-foo skills). I will assign your answer as the correct one by now, and I'm gonna change it as soon as someone answers an effective way of solving this issue.

Comment: @aaamourao I think this is a Eigen team job, to avoid the warning. Perhaps with special <bool> handling.